# Error 500 sending email with Nodemailer (cors)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I can't fix this 500 error that I received in production. In local works fine, but in production (digital ocean), I can't send an email when a new user is register in my nodejs/react app.

The error is: POST https://api.web.com/api/email/new-user 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is my emailController:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Web = require('../models/Web');
const moment = require('moment');


exports.newUserEmail = (req, res) => {

    const  { email }  = req.body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'email200.raiolanetworks.es',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth:{
            user: 'hola@correo.com',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        tls:{
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'no-reply@wcorreo.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Gracias por tu registro',
        text: '¡Bienvenido! Muchas gracias por registrarte',
    } ;
```

In index.js I have this: `app.use(cors())` So I didn't have a cors problem anymore but sending emails I do.

I think the problem is beacuse my server is in api.myweb.com, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help to fix this cors error?

Comment: Do you have any err logs?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have this 500 error if I put console.log in response. If a put the log in err I receive this message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Cuz u got missing curly braces or parenthesis somewhere. As far as I can tell, your newUserEmail function is missing one towards the end.